# How do i check whether the image is already viewed or not?

Tags: javascript

I have 10 number of images and whenever the user clicked on or using the mouse key to open that image , i need to record whether the image is viewed or not and respectively i need to disable the events on image for the current user.

Comment: What have you attempted so far? You can store the image index in an array/object if it's been viewed and assign a property. Let's see some code

Comment: Define what you mean by "opening" an image and what events do you want to disable.

Answer (score 0):

Just set an attribute containing the IDs of the already viewed images. That's easy and quick.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this by adding a event listener on the images

Consider the following code

```
<ul id="test">
    <li><img src="#" alt="img1" /></li>
    <li><img src="#" alt="img2" /></li>
<ul>
```

You can simply achieve the desired effect with the following

```
$('#test').on('click', 'img', function() {
if($(this).hasClass('clicked'))
{
    alert('element was clicked');
    return false;
}
else
{
    alert('you clicked the first time');
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
}
});
```

You can change the listener to a anchor tag since I think that  is what you will be using.